# How to get verified in onActivityResult() that our text is sent to others, after firing sharing Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I am giving some specific coins to user when my app starts, then deduct specific coins on different functions perform. At the end , coins are end and the user facing the screen to re-charge coins by share our app link to his/her friends vis smsApp/WhatsApp/facebook etc. Now I am using ShareIntent with Chooser. I just want get verified in `onActivityResult()` that my link is sent to others or not. But on Activity Results returns `result_code = 1` only in WhatsApp sharing, otherwise `"0"`. I want the number of friends with which link is shared.

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.st_invite_friend_text));
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Invite Friends"),REQUEST_CODE);

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success full", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @adbul I guess you need something a little bit more complex than that, like tracking the sharing with ids on server side ... think about the case where the sharing call is successful, but then the phone has broken internet connection, so the sending actually never leaves the phone

Comment: I just want status that the user has shared content / not? if user shared then I will allow some more coins to use my app. And also number of friends. So i.e: User share content with 10 friends, then I will allow 100 coins to continue on my app

Comment: @adbul what about if the shared content never reach the target user, despite your local method returning to you? Please read my comment carefully. You can't assume users will always have internet, and it will always be working fine 100% of the time.

Comment: Then what's suggestion for this situation?

Comment: Do you handle the server side? Something [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/user-to-user) I think it's the simplest, but alternatively you can do the very same but coding it all yourself. It's not a 2m task, clear?